# Springboot>WebServlet - Pass spring container

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-boot

I have springBoot standalone application. I used @SpringBootApplication, @ServletComponentScan annotations in my standalone application. All my components, beans getting initialized in spring container and prints in the application startup.

Inside my servlet, i invoke handler and beans were coming as null. How do i pass spring container through my servlet ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
public class AStandaloneApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AStandaloneApplication.class, args);
  }
}

@WebServlet("/ba")
public class BAServlet extends SpeechletServlet {

    @Autowired
    private BASpeechletHandler bASpeechletHandler;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        this.setSpeechlet(bASpeechletHandler);
    }   
}

public class BASpeechletHandler implements Speechlet {
  @Autowired
    private BSEngine bSEngine;      

        @Autowired
    private IBotResponseObjToAlexaSpeechletResponseObj botResponseObjToAlexaSpeechletResponseObj;
}
```

The bASpeechletHandler is null in servlet, if i instatiate object in my servlet for bASpeechletHandler and move on then components, services and repository inside bASpeechletHandler also null.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Servlet, it is not standalone anymore, share your code

Comment: Hi @SundararajGovindasamy, Thanks. I updated the question with code snippet

Answer (score 2):

1.**Add the packages** to component scan - similar to this

`@ServletComponentScan(basePackages="org.my.pkg")`

2.Add **one of** the `@Component` annotations into your **BASpeechletHandler** class.

This will make that class eligible for **auto-discovery** of beans.

Comment: No luck.When i print the beans / components registered in the main class it prints all the components and services by having annotation servletComponentScan. But, inside servlet this still components / beans shows null based on component name / beanName.

Comment: I found the answer. public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
  super.init();
  appContext = (ApplicationContext) config.getServletContext().getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
  bASpeechletHandler = (bASpeechletHandler) appContext.getBean("bASpeechletHandler");
 }

Answer (score 0):

May be i little complication in asking. I found the solution. In Web applicationContext i pinged the spring context and got the bean.

```
private ApplicationContext appContext;
private BASpeechletHandler bASpeechletHandler;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        appContext = (ApplicationContext) config.getServletContext().getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
        bASpeechletHandler = (bASpeechletHandler) appContext.getBean("bASpeechletHandler");
    }
```

Thanks.